# mail sent in encoded format without any attachments

Tags: linux, shell-script, mail-command

I am trying to migrate a certain script from AIX to Linux and having issues with the mail functionality. The rest of the script works fine, but the mail function is sending encoded mails with no attachment. Below is the code:

```bash
( cat Body_"$TIMESTAMP" ; /usr/bin/uuencode abc_"$TIMESTAMP" abc_123.xls ; /usr/bin/uuencode def_"$TIMESTAMP" def_123.xls ; /usr/bin/uuencode xyz_"$TIMESTAMP" xyz.xls ; /usr/bin/uuencode pqr_"$TIMESTAMP" pqr_456.xls ; /usr/bin/uuencode mno_"$TIMESTAMP" mno.xls
) | mail -s"From-To-List : ${list}" -c tommy@xyz.com team@xyz.com
```

Comment: Can you confirm the output of the `(cat ... uuencode ...)` command is what you expect? Is the uuencode utility installed?

Comment: Are you expecting the UU-encoded data to be _attached_ to the mail message rather than included in the body of the message?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes very much in a readable format, the same command worked well in AIX doesnt work in Linux though